# ContextMenu in ListView, click on a menuitem doesn't fire the expected command

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu, commandparameter

I have a listview, with contextmenu associated to each listviewitem.
But a click on a menuitem doesn't call the corresponding Command myCommand.
myCommand is linked to a "Execute" and a "Can Execute" methods. The "Can Execute" method works, but not the "Execute" one. it has a parameter.
If I remove the datacontext, the "Execute" Method is called, but the parameter is always null.
My code in xaml:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open Directory " 
                              DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              Command="{Binding OpenLink}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=LocalPath}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Short explanation : Each Item from my list has a property LocalPath. When I right click on an item, and select "Open Directory", it is supposed to open the directory for this item.
Thanks for your help

Niko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `DataContext` changes default binding context for all bindings. If you want to get `LocalPath` from `ListView.SelectedItem` you can use `RelativeSource` binding against that binding only but you need to use `PlacementTarget` to get from `ContextMenu` to `ListView`.

```xml
<MenuItem 
    Header="Open Directory"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem.LocalPath}"
    Command="{Binding OpenLink}"/>
```